# Use of the word conciliated in Call of the wild

Tags: word-usage

"as he looked at each brutal performance, the lesson was driven home to Buck: a man with a club was a lawgiver, a master to be obeyed, though not necessarily conciliated" from Call of the Wild.

I do not understand the use of the word conciliated here.

Comment: Do you understand the use of the word conciliated [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conciliate)?

Comment: Welcome @precursor!  Since I believe your quote may be from "Call of the Wild", please cite your quote and use quotation marks.

Comment: So does it mean not to be friends with. Like some might say a student teacher relation. I do not like this analogy but I can think of no other.

Comment: I'd say it's a dated/formal/archaic usage of OED's sense 5a: *intr. To come to a position of friendliness; to make friends with.* Which they flag as ***Obs[olete]***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conciliate), *conciliate* has a sense “to gain (as goodwill) by pleasing acts”.  This is the sense that Buck (obviously a smart dog) is using; he will avoid crossing any man with a club, but will not go out of his way to chum up with a man in hopes of appeasing him.

Comment: Thanx makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 1):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conciliate) gives "placate" as a definition of the verb "conciliate". I'm not sure I agree with the esteemed editors of the OED when they designate it as obsolete. Although the verb form may be rare, I have heard the adjective "conciliatory" on a regular basis.

Comment: Ngram shows that 'conciliated' is obsolete while 'conciliatory' is still used, but on a downward trend. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conciliated%2Cconciliatory%2C+conciliate&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconciliated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconciliatory%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconciliate%3B%2Cc0

Comment: If you came here for an argument, don't pick Mr. DeBakey. He's a bit conciliatory. Try to see Dr. Barnard, Room 12.